# Problem with comparing screenshots using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

I want to cover ui test cases with automation and was suggested to imply compare screenshots
So the algorithm is the following:
1.I take screenshot of the page using selenium takescreenshot method and stored it in expected results folder
2.That I'm running test case which take screenshot of the same page and then compare it with expected screenshot from the step1

I was using the following method:

```
try {
            // take buffer data from both image files //
            BufferedImage biA = ImageIO.read(fileA);
            DataBuffer dbA = biA.getData().getDataBuffer();
            int sizeA = dbA.getSize();
            BufferedImage biB = ImageIO.read(fileB);
            DataBuffer dbB = biB.getData().getDataBuffer();
            int sizeB = dbB.getSize();
            // compare data-buffer objects //
            if (sizeA == sizeB) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
                    if (dbA.getElem(i) != dbB.getElem(i)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to compare image files");
            return false;
        }
```

And previous week it was working well, but today I ran the same test and it failed, I opened images properties and see that screenshot made today is larger by 0,1 KB then the expected one.
Can't understand the reason
Can it be somehow related to chrome constant background updates and for example browser has some update during the weekend and now the screenshot is little bit different and this way of comparing is wrong?
And if yes, then how can wee do this, I tried popular library Ashot and it also tells me that the screenshot are different

Comment: Check OpenCV library. It can do comparisons and you can specify a threshold so small differences will be ignored.

Comment: I tried to use the method from here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-compare-two-images-using-java-opencv-library 
And after comparing screens of different pages it gave me positive result that the images are the same